# class cocos2d::CCTouch has no member named 'view'

Tags: cocos2d-x

Here the code:

```
CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)( touches->anyObject() );
CCPoint location = touch->locationInView(touch->view());
```

What is wrong?

EDIT:

I think what is being asked here is this:

Why does the following code break in the new cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.13.0-beta release of cocos2d-x while it worked just fine in cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.12.0?

```
CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)( touches->anyObject() );
CCPoint location = touch->locationInView(touch->view());
```

The answer is that the locationInView() method no longer takes an argument. The correct code would be:

```
CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)( touches->anyObject() );
CCPoint location = touch->locationInView();
```

Comment: It's probably because your CCTouch class has no member named "view"

Comment: That should work. Do you have #include "cocos2d.h" and using namespace cocos2d; in your class ?

Comment: If you just create a template application with Cocos2dX after running the script to install the XCode templates, you get this error without modifying anything.
This guy's question is legitimate for that reason, although you should always look at the headers. 
Why cocos2d does this is another pondering to be had. Who updated the templates without testing? Is the real q

Comment: Don't really know why this question was closed. I had the same problem and this question (and answer) helped me. The amount of valid questions that get the "closed as not a real question" is absurd in SO.

Comment: This question is legit, should not have been closed.

Comment: Change CCPoint location = touch->locationInView(touch->view());          into                                                                         CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView(); i used v2.2.5 and it work so keep check your version also if it is not running